# Can data be loaded in Apache Spark RDD/Dataframe on the fly?

Tags: apache-spark

Can data be loaded on the fly or does it have be pre-loaded into the RDD/DataFrame?

Say I have a SQL database and I use the JDBC source to load 1,000,000 records into the RDD. If for example a new records comes in the DB, can I write a job that will add that 1 new record the RDD/Dataframe to make it 1,000,001? Or does the entire RDD/DataFrame have to be rebuilt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by *add (...) record* and *rebuilt*. It is possible to use `SparkContext.union` or `RDD.union` to merge RDDs and  `DataFrame.unionAll` to merge DataFrames.

As long as RDDs, which are merged, use the same serializer there is no need for reserialization but, if the same partitioner is used for both, it will require repartitioning.

Using JDBC source as an example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{max, lit}

val pMap = Map("url" -> "jdbc:..", "dbtable" -> "test")

// Load first batch
val df1 = sqlContext.load("jdbc", pMap).cache

// Get max id and trigger cache
val maxId = df1.select(max($"id")).first().getInt(0)

// Some inserts here...

// Get new records
val dfDiff = sqlContext.load("jdbc", pMap).where($"id" > lit(maxId))

// Combine - only dfDiff has to be fetched
// Should be cached as before
df1.unionAll(dfDiff)
```

If you need an updatable data structure [`IndexedRDD`](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd) implements key-value store on Spark.

Comment: Bassicaly if I have an RDD that has already been loaded with N records. Can I add one more record to that RDD after the fact. Or better say I have a scheduled job that check the SQL DB for latest records and constantly updates the RDD with the new records.

Comment: As shown above you can union with differential data frame, and use cache with forced computation to fetch data, but unless you use system that supports point-in-time queries which can pushed through driver you'll have to take care of providing correct predicates by yourself.